# SSL_accept() throws "Invalid argument" error

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm attempting to create a client/server program, but I'm finding some difficulty continuing with the unfortunately sparse amount of OpenSSL documentation.

My issue:
`SSL_accept` throws an "Invalid Argument" upon executing the following code (simplified):

```
SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx); // ctx is created earlier
SSL_set_fd(ssl, socket); // socket is created earlier as well
BIO * bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_accept());
BIO_set_fd(bio, socket, BIO_NOCLOSE);
SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);
SSL_accept(ssl);
```

I check errors after each method call, and the neither the socket nor the bio goes bad.  There's no indication that anything odd is happening until I attempt calling SSL_accept.  I assume that the ssl object was corrupted somewhere along the way, but I don't have a clue as to how~

**Edit** The SSL object and the BIO object are *not* null at the point of calling SSL_accept().

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you, I have had a difficult time with the dearth of documentation.  So I can't say whether or not the `set_fd` calls are wrong or right, but I got it working without those.  The sequence of calls that I have used successfully is:

```
BIO *sbio = BIO_new_socket( socket, BIO_NOCLOSE );
SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx); 
SSL_set_bio( ssl, sbio, sbio );
SSL_accept( ssl );
```

Comment: Excellent.  The issue was with creating a new bio socket with BIO_s_accept().  I'll do some more digging as to why, but once I just made a standard BIO socket, accept seemed to work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

`SSL_set_fd()` is meant as a convenient *alternative* to manually setting up the BIOs.  It automatically creates a BIO and sets it up - so all you need to do is:

```
SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, socket);
SSL_accept(ssl);
```

Comment: Awesome~  From reading the documentation, I would've never got that.  Thanks!